# How to convert a file full of ASCII to a file full of characters in java

Tags: java

I have a file in which there are ASCII like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ljVW.png)
Now I want to read this file and convert these ASCII to characters. Finally I need to write these characters into another file. How can I do that in java?

Comment: What character encoding is the output?

Comment: Use `InputStreamReader` with "ASCII" as charset-parameter and `OutputSreamWriter` with the needed charset to write into the destination file

Comment: @mattm I think it's "UTF-8"

Comment: @Lothar Sorry I am still confused.I am a novice of java.

Comment: @maxwellhertz Then you should provide the code you have so far where we can see what you've done so far, where it fails and what to do about it

Comment: As you haven't shown any code, I will just give you hints so that you can start coding. Your input file contains integers, so you should use a `Scanner` (search Javadoc for that) to read them. For each integer, you convert it to a character (or more exactly to a character array) with `Character.toChars(int codepoint)`. Just concatenate those char arrays to build a text representation or write them directly to a file. Please feel free to ask a more precise question in you are still stuck later.

Comment: @SergeBallesta There are negative numbers in that file, I'm not sure how `Character#toChars` will react to that ;-)

Comment: @Lothar Sorry I haven't started coding yet....because I have no idea about the task.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Oh...I'm sorry for my  imprecise question and thanks for your hints!

Comment: @maxwellhertz If you don't, how should we do? Your file contains a list of numbers. The numbers range from negative to large values > 127, so it can't just be the codepoint values of (non-ASCII BTW) characters because these numbers would only be positive.

Comment: @Lothar: I did not pay attention to that... IMHO, OP just needs to add 256 to any negative value... I think that 8bits characters are in the [-128 ; 127] range and other unicode characters (more than 8 bits) are the large positive ones.

Comment: @SergeBallesta That would only make sense if the numbers range from -128 to 127 because that's what you often see if you read in a file into a byte array and print out its numbers. Here we have numbers that don't fit into `byte` so I don't have an explanation for that and adding `256` might not be a solution. BTW: Adding 256 is actually wrong you need to do an `int ascii = byteVal & 0xff` to do the conversion.

Comment: @Lothar: You may be right, but I currently have no better idea of what the hell this file can contain...

Comment: Your use of the term "ASCII" is confused. You present the file as a text file and it very well might be encoded using ASCII. The content seems to be a sequence of positive and negative decimal integers. However, the range doesn't seem to correspond to any text character set or encoding, particularly not ASCII. So, before we can answer how to do something, you have to figure what you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

If the target encoding is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), there is no point in writing a program; the desired output file is identical to the input file.

> It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII. Code points with lower numerical values, which tend to occur more frequently, are encoded using fewer bytes. The first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single octet with the same binary value as ASCII, so that valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate each ASCII and insert each into an array.

You can loop over each char using

```
Character.toString((char)yourASCIIchar);
```

This should produce the text representation of the ASCII.

Comment: But I still have a question, how to seperate each ASCII?

Comment: You could use split().
Please read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.